# jquery divs in an array to display

Tags: jquery

I have an array of `DIV` ids as following and in `CSS` they all below to a class with `display:none`.

```
var paintDivs = ["div_2ndSubCategoryID","div_3rdSubCategoryID","div_4thSubCategoryID","div_ColorNameID","div_ColorNoID","div_PaintSizeID"];
```

Long story short, what I now want is to display all `DIV`s in `paintDivs`.

Below is what I have.
Loop iteration is working fine, however the individual `DIV`s in `paintDivs` are still not displaying.

```
jQuery.each(paintDivs, function(idx, valIs){
  $('#' + valIs).css('display');
});
```

I even tried by creating another class in CSS called, `showThis` and set `display:block` and tried to below, still didn't do the trick.

```
jQuery.each(paintDivs, function(idx, valIs){
  $('#' + valIs).attr('class','showThis');
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you atleast try `$('#' + valIs).css('display', 'block');` on your own ?

Comment: @adeneo I didn't try what you've suggested however I tried $('#' + valIs).show(); and that didn't work. And I tried what you've suggested it still didn't work.

Comment: btw I don't understand the down vote, it was a legitimate question after multiple efforts.

Comment: @MadushM: If that's not working, then you are doing something else wrong. Show some more code, or better yet, create a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 3):

You may simply use [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/):

```
$.each(paintDivs, function(idx, valIs) {
    $("#" + valIs).show();
});
```

Otherwise, to change CSS style use [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) correctly:

```
$.each(paintDivs, function(idx, valIs) {
    $("#" + valIs).css("display", "block");
});
```

Comment: That's what I thought, I tried with show() and I tried what you've suggested but none worked.

Answer (score 3):

you are using a getter function of `.css`. Use the setter like below,

```
jQuery.each(paintDivs, function(idx, valIs){
  $('#' + valIs).css('display', 'block');
});
```

Comment: Thanks the explanation. I fixed it as mentioned but still it's not displaying.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
  $('#' + valIs).css('display');
```

Get's the value of the display attribute, you want to set it, which means you should do this to actually set it:

```
  $('#' + valIs).css('display','block');
```

Or more simply, just use:

```
  $('#' + valIs).show();
```

Or, if you wanna get fancy, you could:

```
$("#" + valIs).fadeIn();
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I tried everything you've suggested, none of 'em worked.

Comment: @MadushM: Are you sure you've got the id's correct then? Is there actually a div with the id `div_2ndSubCategoryID`? I.e. `<div id="div_2ndSubCategoryID">`? Also are you running this after the DOM is ready?

Comment: yes `<div id="div_2ndSubCategoryID">` but I know what the issue is. It's not after the DOM is ready. Wow something I overlooked. Thanks  @Matt Burland

Answer (score 2):

Assuming '# + ValIs' is the id you want, changing the display from none to normal is as simple as this:

```
jQuery.each(paintDivs, function(idx, valIs){
  $('#' + valIs).css('display','normal');
});
```

From [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$('#example').css(propertyName)
```

returns the value of propertyName

```
$('#example').css(propertyName, value)
```

sets propertyName to value

Comment: Yes you are correct. I tried what you've mentioned but it's still not displaying. I don't know why it wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

without iterating you can use array join in the selector

```
var divs = ['test1','test3','test5'];
$('#' + divs.join(',#')).show();​
```

Which will build your selector to

```
$('#test1,#test3,#test5')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/JrZBJ/

Comment: That's very interesting take I must say. Thank you, I'm sure it'll come handy.